# ob_get_contents() and apply_filters

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

I'm always looking for ways to improve my coding skills and started to learn about `ob_get_contents()` since I see it being used everywhere.

Therefore I want to improve my code below (maybe with additional hooks) so it would be easier to add extra tab links and panes (inside a child theme) without modifying the original code.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

 <!-- Tab links -->
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  </div>

<?php 

$output = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean(); 

echo apply_filters('theme_tabs', $output);

?>
```

I first thought of using do_actions but what if I want to switch tab links (or panes)?
E.g:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>
```

becomes

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Is there someone who would be willing to give an example of how to change the code and an example of a function I would place inside my child-theme to make modifications inside my tabs?
Extra links to tutorials is also much appreciated.